# Passing JSON data from response to request in Django

Tags: django, node.js, python-requests

I have a Django (1.8.3) view that:

- Makes a GET request to Server A (jetty), which returns JSON data in the body of the response. Then,
- Makes a POST to Server B (node.js), passing the JSON data recieved from Server A in the body of the request.

The JSON data is structured like:

```
{
    name: "foo",
    details: { 
        "date": "today",
        "isCool": "no",
    }, 
    stuff: [
        { 
            "id": "1234",
            "rating": "5",
        }, { 
            "id": "5678",
            "rating": "1",
        },       
    ]
}
```

But I can't figure out how to get the JSON from Server A's response into the request to Server B in my Django view. If I do this:

```
jetty_response = requests.request(method='GET', url=jetty_url)
node_response = requests.request(method="POST", url=node_url, 
                   data=jetty_response.json())
```

I get the JSON object in Server B, but it looks like this:

```
  {
    name: "foo",
    details: [ "date", "isCool"],
    stuff: [ "id", "rating",  "id", "rating"]
```

i.e. the `name` property is correct, but the details dict is instead received as the keyset of the original dict, and the stuff list is received as a flat array of the keysets in all objects in the original dict.

If I instead do this in django:

```
node_response = requests.request(method="POST", url=node_url, 
                  data=json.dumps(jetty_response.json()))
```

I get an empty object in node, and same goes if I do simply:

```
data=jetty_response.content
```

**How do I make this request??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out myself.

As is usually the case, the simplest answer:

```
node_response = requests.request(method="POST", url=node_url, 
               data=jetty_response.content)
```

worked fine once I took a closer look at my log and realized my POSTs were bouncing back 413, and then adjusted the size limit on my bodyParser in express.